# IndexError: list index out of range with random.sample

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
import random
a = [random.sample(xrange(10), 10)]
b = int(input('Enter phone number digit 1 to encrypt'))
c = a[b]
d = int(input('Enter phone number digit 2 to encrypt'))
e = a[d]
f = int(input('Enter phone number digit 3 to encrypt'))
g = a[f]
h = int(input('Enter phone number digit 4 to encrypt'))
i = a[h]
j = int(input('Enter phone number digit 5 to encrypt'))
k = a[j] 
l = int(input('Enter phone number digit 6 to encrypt'))
m = a[l]
n = int(input('Enter phone number digit 7 to encrypt'))
o = a[n]
p = int(input('Enter phone number digit 8 to encrypt'))
q = a[p]
r = int(input('Enter phone number digit 9 to encrypt'))
s = a[r]
t = int(input('Enter phone number digit 10 to encrypt'))
u = a[t]

b = str(b)
d = str(d)
f = str(f)
h = str(h)
j = str(j)
l = str(l)
n = str(n)
p = str(p)
r = str(r)
t = str(t)


print('This is your original phone number: ')
time.sleep(1)
print(b+d+f+h+j+l+n+p+r+t)
print('This is your encrypted phone number')
time.sleep(1)
print(c,e,g,i,k,m,o,q,s,u)
```

Even when I type a number under 10 like 4 or 2 it gives me an error when it asks me for the first digit of my program. Here is the error below. I know this program overall sucks and that the random module is not supposed to be used with encryption, but I made this program to test my skills about the `random.sample` module.

```
c = a[b]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This is not python3 code. Python3 does not have `xrange`. Please post the real code

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html python 3 does: random.sample(population, k)

To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an range() object as an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a large population: sample(range(10000000), 60).

Comment: i tried range instead of xrange and still got the same error.

Comment: I'm going to guess that on the prompts, you entered numbers between 1 and 10. This /would/ cause an error, as `a` has only 10 elements, meaning that its last element is at index 9. Try `b = int(input("Enter ..."))-1`

Comment: That only works for the number 1. What is i want to type in a 2 or 3 as my first digit.

Comment: Try turning your `a=[random.sample(...)]` into `a = random.sample(...)` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You code could be significantly simplified, removing all of the unclearly-named variables, repetition and risk of `IndexError`

```
import random
import string

digits = random.sample(range(10), 10)

phone = input("Enter a phone number: ")
encrypt = [digits[int(c)] for c in phone if c in string.digits]

print("Here is the encrypted phone number: {0}".format("".join(map(str, encrypt))))
```

As it stands, if a user enters a two- (or more) digit number you will be past the end of `a`.

You can easily decrypt, too, using `list.index`:

```
phone = [digits.index(i) for i in encrypt]
```